# How can I upsert using Mongoose based on _id?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, coffeescript, mongoose, upsert

When I do this:

```
client_id = req.param("client_id") ? null
client =
  name: req.param "clientName"
  status: 'active'

Client.update {_id: client_id}, client, {upsert: true}, (err, updRes) ->
  if err
    res.json
      error: "Couldn't create client"
  else
    res.json client
```

It will create a new client record, except with a `null` `_id` field. I assume that's because the insert part of the upsert looks to the `query` to create the document. How can I do it so that if no doc is found, then insert a new `ObjectId`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if you have figured this one out yet, but in case you don't want to run into trouble with unique key constraints like Mustafa mentioned above, the way I've done it is by using mongoose's [findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findByIdAndUpdate):

```
// require mongoose

client_id = req.param("client_id") ? new mongoose.Types.ObjectId
client =
  name: req.param "clientName"
  status: 'active'

Client.findByIdAndUpdate client_id, client, {upsert: true}, (err, updRes) ->
  if err
    res.json
      error: "Couldn't create client"
  else
    res.json client
```

I've never written CoffeeScript, so forgive me if some of that syntax is wrong, but I think it should be fairly obvious what I'm trying to do.

One thing to notice is that you need to make sure client_id is neither an empty string (as that would cause an 'Invalid ObjectID' error) nor null (because mongoose seems infer the new document's id from the one you're querying for). In case it is, I create a new ObjectId, which will cause the query to miss and therefore create a new document with that ID since I pass {upsert: true}.

This seems to have solved the problem for me.

Comment: After Mongoose v 4.0 you need to explicitly set the `new` option to `true`, as the default prior to 4.0 was `true` but is now `false` after 4.0.   Ref [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30396464/404699) and [these release notes](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/4.0-Release-Notes#backwards-breaking-changes).

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do with Mongoose is to call save on the client, Mongoose will figure out on its own if it's an update or an insert:

```
client_id = req.param("client_id") ? null
client_data =
  name: req.param "clientName"
  status: 'active'
  _id: client_id

client = new Client(client_data)
client.save (err) ->
  if err
    res.json
      error: "Couldn't save client"
  else
    res.json client
```

Note: Client is a Mongoose model.

Comment: So no need for upserts any more?

Comment: I can tell you I have actually used this in my code, both for inserts and update and it works, so no need for upserts. Bless Mongoose ODM :)

Comment: If the client_id is null, will this save with a new `_id`?

Comment: Can you explain more, @Mustafa?

Comment: confirmed this fails on an indexed field.  ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongoose-orm/fIgL55-9838

Comment: Looks like this is no longer an issue?  I'm able to get a failed unique.

Comment: Disregard, not happening like I had thought