# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate upsert returns null document on initial insert

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This basic Mongoose model code returns a null result (gameMgr) on the initial call, but works on subsequent calls. Shouldn't it return a populated result object on the initial upsert? The mongo record exists, and running the code a second time in the identical situation, everything works fine as there is no insert.

If a null result object is expected, what is the appropriate pattern to create a new object? (or do I reload with *another* db call and descend further into callback madness?)

```
GameManagerModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
    game._id,
    {$setOnInsert: {user_requests:[]}}, 
    {upsert: true},
    function(err, gameMgr) {
        console.log( gameMgr ); // NULL on first pass, crashes node
        gameMgr.addUserRequest( newRequest );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Mongoose 4.0, the default value for the `new` option of `findByIdAndUpdate` (and `findOneAndUpdate`) has changed to `false` (see [release notes](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/4.0-Release-Notes#backwards-breaking-changes)).  This means that you need to explicitly set the option to `true` to get the doc that was created by the upsert:

```
GameManagerModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
    game._id,
    {$setOnInsert: {user_requests:[]}}, 
    {upsert: true, new: true},
    function(err, gameMgr) {
        console.log( gameMgr );
        gameMgr.addUserRequest( newRequest );
    }
);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Ye ol' hidden parameter buried in ye ol' release notes strikes again. Documentation currently says "new: bool - true to return the modified document rather than the original. defaults to true"

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: I was a little confused as to why mongoose changed the default.. seems odd to me